# Changing to color of a cell due to a percentage between two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

My scenario is:
Column D: Hrs Allotted
Column E: Hrs Worked
Column F: Hrs Remaining

I want F to change color once the "Hrs Worked" reach 50% of "Hrs Allotted"
I have entered the subtraction formula in column F to subtract E from D.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnF, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=D2>2*E2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, choose your formatting, OK, OK.

If formatting of F1 bothers you, select an unformatted cell, copy it and Paste Special..., Formats (only) over the top of F1.